# Для чего в параметре INT(size) при создании таблицы, нужно указывать size

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Для чего в параметре  INT(size) при создании таблицы, нужно указывать размер? Это размер количества допустимых символов, которые будут записаны в колонку? Какая разница  если я напишу :

**так**

```
create table MyTest2(id_use int (1) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    position5 varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                    PRIMARY KEY (id_use));
```

**или так**

```
create table MyTest2(id_use int (100) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    position5 varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                    PRIMARY KEY (id_use));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство ответов по таким вопросам есть в документации.

В качестве расширения стандарта ANSI/ISO SQL92 MySQL позволяет при необходимости указывать количество показываемых пользователю символов целого числа. Это необязательное указание количества выводимых символов используется для дополнения слева выводимых значений, которые содержат символов меньше, чем заданная ширина столбца, однако не накладывает ограничений ни на диапазон величин, которые могут храниться в столбце, ни на количество разрядов, которые могут выводиться для величин, у которых количество символов превосходит ширину данного столбца. Если дополнительно указан необязательный атрибут ZEROFILL, свободные позиции по умолчанию заполняются нолями. Например, для столбца, объявленного как INT(5) ZEROFILL, величина 4 извлекается как 00004.

Следует учитывать, что если в столбце для целых чисел хранится величина с количеством символов, превышающим заданную ширину столбца, могут возникнуть проблемы, когда MySQL будет генерировать временные таблицы для некоторых сложных связей, так как в подобных случаях MySQL полагает, что данные действительно поместились в столбец имеющейся ширины.

http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/numeric-types.html

Comment: Так а для чего это нужно? И какую лучше величину устанавливать? Не понятно. Можете объяснить простым языком?

Comment: Так-же не ясно как лучше, задавать этот параметр или не задавать. Может его оставить как есть? но тогда встаёт вопрос, не будет ли он слишком много есть ресурсов... Вообщем ничего ровным счетом не ясно.

Comment: Грубо говоря это означает выравнивание при выводе к примеру на ту же консоль, не более. Вы пользуетесь консолью при работе с MySql? Если да, то можете посмотреть разницу, если нет и Вам не нужен ZEROFILL, то просто игнорируйте этот параметр и не указывайте его.

Comment: То есть лучше вообще не указывать значение размера? id_use  int  (это не указываем -(1) ) AUTO_INCREMENT  ...... Но если не указывать, то по умолчанию указывается (11). Так что лучше делать?

Comment: @semiromid, это не размер, это описатель заполнения. Да, просто не указывайте. Это сделано для тех, кто пользуется специальными консольными утилитами и влияет исключительно на **внешний вид для пользователя** в этих утилитах. По умолчанию 11, что бы все цифры внешне отображались в них.

Comment: @semiromid, если есть знания Си, С++, Java, PHP, то можете получить аналогию с функцией printf которая форматирует числа при выводе в консоль: `printf("%.11d", value);`. Кроме визуального представления ни на что не влияет и лучше оставить по умолчанию для тех, кто возможно захочет просмотреть данные через консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Никакой размер не устанавливайте. Будьте ближе к стандарту:

```
create table test_int(id int, id1 int(1), id5 int(5));
insert into test_int values (666666,666666,666666);
select * from test_int;
```

Мне представляется плохим тоном смешивать хранение и форматирование.

Comment: Так стоп! Если никакой размер не устанавливать, тогда он устанавливается по умолчанию . По умолчанию он равен - 11

Comment: Одиннадцать чего?
Зависит от реализации, но обычно
int - 4 байта
smallint - 2 байта
bigint - 8 байт

Comment: по умолчанию равен - id1 int(11)   если не указывать  int()